# How to debug a node.js application in VS2015?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015

Given:

1. A brand new installation of VS 2015 (enterprise)
2. Installed Node.js Tools for VS (https://www.visualstudio.com/features/node-js-vs)
3. Installed Node.js
4. Created a new project using the **Basic Node.js Express 4 Application** project template.

The application runs fine and works as expected, but VS does not respect any breakpoint I set - "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No code has been loaded for this code location" is what I get instead and the breakpoints are disabled:
[image]

Googling it was useless.

Any ideas?

Comment: see if this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167222/debug-java-script-with-visual-studio-2015-on-chrome-or-firefox

Comment: @mike123 That link is discussing client-side JavaScript run within a browser. [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) is a separate environment, commonly used for server-side JavaScript.

Comment: Same problem, I installed Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 Enterprise Update 2 and I can't replicate the problem. The application immediately breaks. And when I click Continue it proceeds normally and opens a new browser window. What version is your VS 2015? Probably they fixed something in the update

Comment: I have Update 2 as well - see **EDIT 1**.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you generating source maps.

If you do not have a tsconfig.json in your project, then check the Visual Studio properties page. Under the *TypeScript Build* tab, ensure that *Generate source maps* is selected. [Example Visual Studio property page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSmta.png).

If you are using a tsconfig.json, make sure you are generating source maps in the *compilerOptions* section.

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```